# Is there any ML classifier that generally works best for NLP projects?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, text-classification

I've written a program that reads word vectors from a particular website and makes conclusary classifications.

I'm getting the highest accuracy and F Score for a RandomForestClassifier. I'm not sure what I can do to make this accuracy higher except changing the model. I tried to use MLPs but landed with a lower accuracy. Should I use some other neural network?

Does anyone know what models generally work for such NLP based programs?

In a nutshell, what the program does is look through the HTML of a given webpage for certain features, vectorize the words it can find (using predefined vector spaces) and make classifications based on that. I'm getting an accuracy over 90% for the RandomForestClassifier. Any help?

Comment: Try posting this question on AI stack exchange. Also helpful if you can share some examples of your data and categories. Your question is too general and broad for SO right now.

Comment: @AdnanS Sure. I can explain the working in a nutshell. Is that fine?

Comment: >90% is quite good result for text classification - you could perhaps find a MLP model that gives a higher accuracy but the effort to find one may not be worth the investment of time and you may also lose speed at inference time

Comment: There's no "to-go" model that works for NLP in general. It depends on how much data you have, how clean your data is and what problem you're solving... The knowledge comes with the experience you gain in the field.